# matlab histogram with same x axis, but reasonable number of bins

Tags: matlab, histogram

I want to draw multiple histograms with the following property.

The data for each histogram are different and have different ranges.

Each histogram's x-axis should have the same range, from 0-10000.

For each histogram, the range of data might not be from 0-10000, but rather be from 0-2500 or some other number with the minimum greater or equal to zero, and the maximum smaller or equal to 10000.

For each histogram, I want 10 bins in the range of interest (so 10 bins between 0-2500 for example).

Is there a built in method that does this? Or should I implement this on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `hist()` for the data and use `set()` to set your axis to `(0,10000)`.

For instance:

```
mymean=2000;
mystd=200;
a=random('normal',mymean,mystd,1000,1);
hist(a,10);
set(gca,'XLim',[0 10000])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`hist()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) to plot or [`histc()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) to count.

Comment: Yes, the histogram function.

However, the parameters it gives are "bins" which indicates the total number of bins, and "xcenter", which is an array of xcenters. I want to indicate a range ([0 10000]), and want it to intelligently create n bins, such that there are exactly 10 bins which have a nonzero number of things in them. For example, while I want the range to be ([0 10000]), the range of the data might be only ([2500 3500]); in that case, I want 10 bins between 2500 and 3500, and thus a total of 100 bins.

Comment: `hist()` does not require `xcenter`, that is an alternative syntax. It determines automatically the range and it partitions in the number of bins you specified. However, you cannot ensure to have them non-empty in which case you would need a more sophisticated routine to detect interruptions.

Comment: I am under the impression that you misread the question. It was not "how to make a historgram with a specific number of bins". It was "is there a built-in method to make a histogram with a reasonable number of bins with a fixed range".

Comment: In your question you state: *I want 10 bins in the range of interest*. Then, you want a reasonable amount of bins, whatever that means. The point is, `hist()` behaves as I commented, is there a function that does what you want, no.

Comment: But I also want the xlim of the graph not necessarily to be be just the range of interest.


"Each histogram's x-axis should have the same range, from 0-10000", and that might have nothing to do with the range of interest.

Comment: Setting the xlims of the axis is trivial and irrelevant to the main problem, i.e. that you do not have a function that partitions the inverse image of your Xs into n bins.

Comment: It was pretty relevant since it was part of the main problem, as defined by my question, which was not "how to make a histogram with n bins". Yeah, changing the xlim is pretty trivial. I just never thought of treating the histogram as a plot.